# How to compare DataFrame with a list and output result into csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of 100 words

```
a = ['Noodle', 'Instant', 'Flavour', 'Ramen', 'Chicken' ...]
```

And I have a DataFrame of a column from a csv file that contains a description of the item. 
Output which looks like

```
1       Noodles Spicy Hot Sesame Spicy Hot Sesame Guan...
2                           Cup Noodles Chicken Vegetable
3                           GGE Ramen Snack Tomato Flavor
4                                         Singapore Curry
...
```

I would like to compare the descriptions from the DataFrame with the 100 words in list "a", and only keep the words from the description that appear in the list and output it back out to the csv file. Although I'm not sure how to go about doing that, any suggestions?

Comment: `df["column_name"].str.findall("|".join(a),flags=re.I)`?

Answer (score 0):

I might approach it by finding the intersection between the two sets of words:

```
In [35]: df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=r'\s{2,}',header=None)

In [36]: df
Out[36]: 
   0                                                  1
0  1  Noodles Spicy Hot Sesame Spicy Hot Sesame Guan...
1  2                      Cup Noodles Chicken Vegetable
2  3                      GGE Ramen Snack Tomato Flavor
3  4                                    Singapore Curry

s = df[1].str.split().explode().str.strip() # get the words in a long series

In [39]: pd.Series(list(set(s).intersection(set(a))))
Out[39]: 
0      Ramen
1    Chicken
dtype: object
```

Note that `Noodles` does *not* match with `Noodle`. If this isn't what you want try @HenryYik's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it with isin() function.

<strike>filteredDFrame = dFrame["description"].isin(a)</strike>

Edit: Sorry. This is not the solution. isin() compares but returns a boolean list. You could possibly build on that, but there are better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, if you'd like to traverse the dataframe and replace the description with word which appear in *list a*, you can try my code:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('xxx.csv')
for word in a:
    for index,description in enumerate(data['description']):#maybe your dataframe uses anathor name,change it
        if re.search(word,description):
             data.loc[index]['description'] = word

data.to_csv('xxx.csv')
```